# How to compile first haskell program

Tags: haskell

I’d like to start learning haskell and I cannot get it to work, so basically I have installed the stack, created a new project using the stack new command.I also run stack update, stack upgrade.And now I have an app folder, a source folder and much more stuff.I genuinely admit that I have absolutely no idea of what I am doing however I have seen in the docs that each command and the stack itself are all very well explained.However that is a quite theoretical explanation, I am just trying to run my first hello world program as I always did in every programming language I have learnt so far :).Could you help me?This is a screenshot with the current structure of my project directory.[Image of dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYHgh.png).As you can see I also tried to run the ghc or ghci commands but without any luck.Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: hi, if you are using `stack` I'd recommend to use `stack` only commands. For openning a `ghci` session within your project run `stack repl`; for building you project: `stack build`; for running you application `stack run` (using the default `stack` project, this should output "hello world"); finally, use `stack install` to build your binary and copy it automatically into you binaries directory (system dependent. In linux `~/.local/bin`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm gonna post a somewhat controversial opinion here, and say that if what you want is a hello-world with a minimum of fuss, then stack is not the right tool. Just use GHC directly. Simply make a file, say, `hello.hs`, that contains:

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"
```

Then at the command line, here are some things you can do to run it; there are three options here, and you only need to choose one.

```
% runhaskell hello.hs
Hello, world!
% ghc hello.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )
Linking hello ...
% ./hello
Hello, world!
% ghci hello.hs
> main
Hello, world!
```

You may need to tweak some commands slightly if you are on Windows; the main one I think is that `./hello` would be `hello.exe`.

Comment: Yes, but I might want to do something more in the future :)).However, thank you very much for your advice and I am starting to learn about stack so that I can be aware of how these things work.